# How to insert banner along with the text in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

How do I insert a banner along with my text I have in my APP? I saw an app that did this, I will insert the image below. The link to access this APP is:https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/lego-mosaic.html

Notice it has the text and a blue banner. I would like to do something similar to this. Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Executable code below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(
  title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
  
  tabPanel("",
           
           br(),
           hr(),
           
           h2(HTML("Project <b>Description</b>"), 
              style="text-align:center; color: blue;"),
           hr(),
           div(
             style = "width: 75%; margin: auto;",
             h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                                      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                                      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
                                      Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                                      like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"),
                style="text-align:center"),
             h2(HTML("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                                      Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                                      when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                                      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic 
                                      typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of 
                                      Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
                                      like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"),
                style="text-align:center"))
  )
)




server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is done with the package ***shinyDashboard***.

Comment: Thanks! But there is no way to make some kind of 
strip/band?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want. What about that:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
    style = 
      "height: 80px; background-color: blue; width: 100%; position: absolute; right:0;",
    div(
      style = "height: 100%; background-color: cyan; position: relative; width: fit-content;",
      tags$p(
        "Here some text vertically centered", 
        style = 
          "position: relative; top: 50%; -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px;"
      )
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That's exactly it, but I would like to make this strip in cyan for the part that has my text.